# make: 'file' is up to date, followed by nothing to be done for all

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I'm trying to create a basic makefile for my program. It looks like this:

```
all: example
example: example.c
    gcc -o example example.c
clean:
    rm example
```

If I 'make clean', then enter 'make', I receive "make: Nothing to be done for all".

If I make a slight change to my source code, save it, then run make, I receive "gcc -o example example.c

If I enter 'make example', I receive "'example' is up to date. I'm using indents, not spaces, before 'gcc' and 'rm' in the make file, and the indents are not secretly spaces. I'm sure it's something I'm doing wrong with my makefile, but I would appreciate some help figuring out what mistake I'm making.
edit: changed 'clear make' to 'make clean'

Comment: The behavior you described were just working as expected.

Comment: You may try `touch example.c ; make example` to check whether it behaves correctly when example.c is changed.

Comment: `clear make` and `make clear` are not the same thing.

Comment: Furthermore, you defined `make clean`, not `make clear`

Comment: you are correct, that was my mistake. when I enter 'make clean', I receive 'rm example', but I still am not able to get the program to run from the make file. edit: also, where would I include "touch example.c; make example", as listed above?

Comment: You want Make to *run* the program? Then add this line to the `all` rule: `./$<`

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, then `make clean` followed by either `make` or `make all` does not regenerate the `example` executable.  I'm unable to reproduce the problem.  After `make clean`, either `make` or `make all` or `make example` recompiles `example` without me needing to touch the source code.  You should use `rm -f example` so that the cleanup does not fail if there is no `example` executable to remove (e.g. if you run `make clean` twice in a row).

Comment: Do you have a `clean` file in source directory? If yes `make clean` will not run. To avoid this please use `.PHONY` directive (it tells to `make` the `clean` target isn't a file target).

Answer (score 0):

if you enter

```
make
```

then the 'example' program will be generated.

then, If you then enter

```
make example
```

nothing will happen because the program 'example' is already done and its dependencies ('example.c') time stamp has not changed.